# What does the largest number on the Heroes of the Storm scoreboard indicate?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

What does the largest number on the end-of-game scoreboard in Heroes of the Storm mean?

It's the number next to your team's final level and immediately adjacent the crossed swords.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the number of hero takedowns your team had over the game.

[image: Bottom of the score screen]

In this example, my team killed the enemy team 20 times.

Note this won't be a perfect sum of the takedown columns for each team.  That's because each hero gets credit for a takedown if they were in the area or did damage to that hero within a short time of that hero's death.